# java- Read data from a file for further processing

Tags: java, arrays, file

I'm new to java and I would like to ask you for help. I have some data stored in a txt file, each line holds three integers, separated by space. I would like to read the data from the file and then put this data in arrays for further processing, if certain conditions are met (in my case- third int is greater than 50). I read some questions about how to read the number of lines in a file or the file itself, but I can't seem to combine it all together to make it work. The latest version of the code looks like this:

```
public class readfile {

private Scanner x;

    public void openFile(){
        try{
            x = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("could not find file");
        }
    }

    public void readFile() throws IOException{

            LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File("file.txt")));
            int i = lnr.getLineNumber();
            int[] table1 = new int[i];
            int[] table2 = new int[i];
            while(x.hasNextInt()){
            int a = x.nextInt();
            int b = x.nextInt();
            int c = x.nextInt();
            for (int j=0; j< table1.length; j++) 
            {
                if(c > 50)
                {
                table1[j]=a;
                table2[j]=b;  
                }

            }
            }System.out.printf(" %d %d", table1, table2);


    }         
    public void closeFile(){
        x.close();
    }
}
```

main is located in another file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    readfile r = new readfile();
    r.openFile();
    try {
    r.readFile();
    }
    catch (Exception IOException) {}   //had to use this block or it wouldn't compile
    r.closeFile();
}
```

when I use %d on printf method i don't see anything, when I use %s I get some gibberish on the output like

```
[I@1c3cb1e1 [I@54c23942
```

what should I do to make it work (ie. print pairs of a b when c is > 50)?

Thanks in advance for any help, and sorry if this turns out to be some blatantly obvious problem, but I really ran out of ideas on how to improve this :)

Comment: You're telling your program to print two integers (%d), but passing two arrays of integers.

Comment: where is x coming from in  `while(x.hasNextInt()){` ? Do you want to parse the entire file first and then print the numbers or do you want to do it on the fly line by line ? This can be achieved in much simpler way. Also, you need to print the value from the index of an array. not the array itself : System.out.printf(" %d %d", table1, table2);

Comment: There's also no good reason to store your pairs in a table if this code is standalone. Just print them inside your `if` statement.

Comment: `catch (Exception IOException)`: you always have to catch explicitly thrown exceptions in java

Comment: Your catch block is somewhat odd.  Your `IOException` is a variable, not the type of execption being caught.  Also, empty exception blocks are rearly useful.  Finally, try moving all the logic in `main` into your `ReadFile` class.  By the way, *CamelCase* is conventional for classes.

Comment: Is there another way to get the number of lines in the file? The way I'm currently using it I have to add this block that does nothing, or it doesn't compile other way, as I keep getting error msg: //Tst1 is the file where main is, nothing else really.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown at tst1.Tst1.main

Answer (score 0):

You cannot print an entire array using `%d`. Loop through the array and print each value separately.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting gibberish output because you are printing the Array References in `printf()`

For individual values use a loop like..

```
for(int i:table1){
System.out.print(""+i)
}
```

**OR**

To print in pairs substitute the following code...

```
       if(c > 50)
         {
            table1[j]=a;
            table2[j]=b;  
            System.out.printf("%d %d",a,b);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot format your arrays as an int using printf.  If you want to print the entire contents of your arrays, then use the helper function `Arrays.toString(array)`.

E.g.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(table1));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correct you have a file like

```
12 33 54
93 223 96
74 743 4837
234 324 12
```

and if the third integer is greater than 50 you want to store the first two?

```
List<String> input = FileUtils.readLines(new File("file.txt"), Charset.forName( "UTF-8" ));
HashMap<Integer, Integer> filtered = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

for (String current : input) {
    String[] split = current.split(" ");
    if (Integer.parseInt(split[2]) > 50) 
        filtered.put(Integer.parseInt(split[0]), Integer.parseInt(split[1]))
}
System.out.println(filtered);
```